# Opencart :: is it possible to create event like change header without VQMOD or OCMOD?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-events

I want to add one script inside the head, however using event I could not find way how it works.

I had install one event which added one script but it displays before HTML tag. But i want to display inside head tag.

**extention/module/shop.php**

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleShop extends Controller {
    public function index() {
      //$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/css/test.css');
      //$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/js/test.js');
      echo "<script src="catalog/view/javascript/js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>";
    }
}
```

**Admin**

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleShop extends Controller {
public function install() {
        $this->model_setting_event->addEvent('shop', 'catalog/view/common/header/before', 'extension/module/shop/index');
    }

    public function uninstall() {
        $this->model_setting_event->deleteEventByCode('shop');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your event with this trigger:

```
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('shop', 'catalog/controller/common/header/before', 'extension/module/shop/index');
```

And your `shop.php` should be:

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleShop extends Controller {
    public function index(&$route = '', &$data = array(), &$output = '') {
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/js/test.js');
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried with this code, you may also check my above code.. I had follow same thing with default opencart theme. however I got solution from different way.